# Croppic.js conflicting with prototype.js in Magento

Tags: magento, prototypejs

I am trying to use croppic library to crop image in magento and its conflicting with prototype.js
http://www.croppic.net/

Please help!!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all js and put again through local.xml. This should solve your problem.
You can use it on global node.

```
<action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>FILENAMEPATH+NAME.css</name></action>
```

and then add the js again through addJs in your preferential order. If the problem still persists, then you could try in particular page handler.

Comment: I want to use croppic library on product page and I think prototype.js is required in it.

Comment: Yeah so, remove and add again through LOCAL.XML on the <catalog_product_view> layout handler. I think it's a jquery plugin so add it after jquery. Learn more about noConflict issue in magento.